# Which part(s) of the ArcMap user interface uses the Rogue Wave Objective Grid(OG1200ASU.DLL)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, versioning

I'm trying to troubleshoot ArcMap 10 crashing when I reconcile a version and I think it is OG1200ASU.DLL causing the problem.  I'm guessing it's the attribute table or the attribute inspector.

```
GetProcAddress(0x773D0000 [c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.DLL], "InitCommonControlsEx") called from "c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_x-ww_a96f9c14\MFC90U.DLL" at address 0x78A43931 and returned 0x773D4088.
LoadLibraryW("DbgHelp.dll") called from "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\AFCORE.DLL" at address 0x007144A4.
Loaded "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" at address 0x28380000.  Successfully hooked module.
DllMain(0x28380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" called.
DllMain(0x28380000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
LoadLibraryW("DbgHelp.dll") returned 0x28380000.
GetProcAddress(0x28380000 [c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL], "MiniDumpWriteDump") called from "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\AFCORE.DLL" at address 0x007144B4 and returned 0x283DD4F0.
Second chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\OG1200ASU.DLL" at address 0x064A310B.
Exited "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\ARCMAP.EXE" (process 0x1298) with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).
```

---

**Update:**
I've narrowed my issue to the attribute table.  When I start up ArcMap with the attribute table window docked, edit, then reconcile...ArcMap crashes.

If I start up ArcMap, close the attribute table window <strike>(or auto-hide)</strike>, then edit, then reconcile...success!

If I start up ArcMap, close the attribute table window <strike>(or auto-hide)</strike>, then open the attribute table window again, then **dock** (*which effectively puts the attribute table window in same condition as it was on startup*) , then edit, then reconcile...success!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156285/ArcMap_Reconcile_CrashReproduce.avi

Comment: just to check you are running sp1.   http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=listPatches&PID=160

Comment: Yes, I am on SP1.

Comment: The OG1200ASU.DLL file version is 12.0

Comment: Jay -- looking at the StingrayStudio ObjectiveGrid User guide -- the main use of the library is preparing Grided tabular reports from various data sources. http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/stingray/cd47/ObjectiveGridUG.pdf and http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/stingray/CD50/RWSS10_ReleaseNotes.pdf  -- Any chance your issues with ArcGIS 10 crashing is the obscurely documented need for update to MSXML4 SP3 and interaction with Geodatabase?  -- Stuart

Comment: Stuart, good suggestion, but I'm at SP3.  I'm also going to update the question with some new information.

Comment: Jay--you've shown the ObjectiveGrid component crash only occurs when you open a MXD Map document saved with the Attribute table **docked open** for one of the layers, as you've nicely proven. Why not open a bug with ESRI and then avoid saving with a docked attribute table until ESRI gets the behavior corrected at the next SP or major release?

Comment: I do have an open issue w/ ESRI and I'm working through some things with them to narrow this down a little (they can't replicate this behavior).  I'll update this question on Monday with my notes from earlier today.  I think once I can get them to recreate the crash, they will  log  the bug.

Comment: Jay--hope you can get it all resolved. One thing I recall is that a fellow over on the ESRI forums (Jason Lyon -- conwayGISCoor) had similar problems with just one feature of a polygon class that when a **table join** was done against it, it would crash ArcMap when using the Attribute Table for edits. He eliminated that one feature and all was good with Attribute Table edits. Maybe you could dummy up a known good set of data in a fresh MXD to eliminate a data structure or formatting issue as the cause of the og1200asu.dll error?

Comment: I narrowed it down to the feature layers.  If I create a new MXD with new layers (by adding the featureclasses) and reconcile...no crash.  If I paste in the layers from the old MXD, then reconcile...crash.  My MXD originated in 9.3, so ESRI's resolution was for me to rebuild all MXDs that are used in editing in ArcGIS 10.  And they promptly closed the incident calling it a corruption issue...premature assessment in my opinion.  No bug.

Comment: Fix #1: MXD Doctor (`Save a Copy` had no effect).  That should have been the first thing I did--arcmap troubleshooting 101!

Comment: Fix #2: Move all layers in the map into a group layer.  Save the group layer to a layer file.  Create a new MXD. Add the group layer file to the map.  Move all the layers out of the group layer and delete the empty group layer. Save the MXD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Jay, it's cheap since you've done the major lifting, but I'll go ahead and answer :)

ObjectiveGrid is the [StingrayStudio](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/stingray/CD52/ObjectiveGridUG.pdf) (by Rogue Wave) programming widget set that ESRI uses for **grided tabular data presentation and manipulation** in ArcGIS.  At ArcGIS 9.3.1 it is version 9.04 (og903asu.dll) and at ArcGIS 10 it is version 12.00 (og1200asu.dll).

To me, it looks like all ArcGIS graphical table based manipulations uses the ObjectiveGrid toolset. Over on the ESRI forums there have been multiple users and threads with issues regards Attribute table edits, for example NIM061049 is an ugly ctl-C, ctl-V deficiency that remains outstanding (NIM059999, NIM059402, NIM058769, NIM058886, NIM058820 are ESRI attribute related bugs supposedly fixed in SP1, certainly some may be ObjectiveGrid tabular data related).  Unfortunately, ESRI doesn't really document the inner workings their GUIs and OO-glue for external reference. We're left guessing as to the exact role of their 3rd party development components and have to dig with tools like Process Monitor to peek under the hood, or to help identify problem components when crashes occur.

As users, the DbgHelp.dll error report we are presented submits a dump file back to ESRI and they can extract details of the crash for "internal use". Not sure how much they will provide back to the user community. And when I've dealt with ESRI tech support on issues, I've often had to run a Process Monitor log and tease out the offending modules in advance, as you've done for the og1200asu.dll on docked Attribute Table use in ArcMap.

Answer (score 2):

That is the Open GL 2.0 compliant component according to ESRI OpenGL extensions viewer 3.31 is available here http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/changes.html

Comment: Mapperz- I'm confused, are you saying that OG1200ASU.DLL is an ESRI provided component? Or suggesting that Jay is having a problem with OpenGL compliance with his installation? Can you expand any on the "according to ESRI" regards this particular DLL. Thanks! Stuart

Comment: I'm confused by the answer as well, but 3 others thought it was a good answer and I figured I must be missing something.   I did run the extension viewer--OpenGL 2.1 and the rendering tests check out.